# Tomcat Websockets -- javax.websocket.Session.isOpen() not always accurate?

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, tomcat8

I have an Apache Tomcat instance which is serving up websockets. It is generally working well. However, there is one problem that I can't quite understand.

I have an instance of javax.websocket.Session and when I go session.isOpen() I ordinarily get the true state of the session. So, if it is connected, I ordinarily get "true" and if the client is disconnected, I get "false."

However, in one particular case, session.isOpen appears to be lying. If I have a client (say, a browser-based websocket) which drops its internet connection, on the server side (in Java on Tomcat) I find that  javax.websocket.Session.isOpen() returns "true"!!!! I am perplexed by this.

What's worse is: When I try to send to that endpoint, it doesn't throw an exception. So not only does the session not properly report isOpen, but it pretends to have carried out its task!

Why is this happening? If it must happen how can I know, with the endpoint object and/or its session object, when this has happened? Or is there some setting that I can make these zombie sessions disappear (hence throwing an exception when I try to send to them.. currently they accept messages as if they worked)?

Note: I am using Java 8 and have replicated this issue in Apache Tomcat 8.0.14 and 8.0.21 (the latest version).

Comment: Would you please post sample code?

Comment: I suspect this is just a consequence of how TCP works. You can silently drop the connection at one endpoint with no way for the other endpoint to notice it until it tries to send some actual data.

Comment: biziclop. Thanks for comment. Oh, it would be workable if it noticed when I try to send a message. However, the problem is that it lets me send the message and returns no exceptions. So it doesn't even notice that the session is gone when I do my send!!

Comment: @MarkNenadov If you send data through a half-open connection, it should fail eventually. But they keyword here is "eventually", as simply putting bytes into the socket's outputstream doesn't guarantee that those bytes are sent, you need to flush the connection to force the emptying of all buffers along the network stack. Even then the error will arrive asynchronously, so you won't get an exception straight away on the flush operation.